# Order of tables in "FROM" returns different results in Pervasive database

Tags: sql, pervasive

Why does the order of the "FROM" seem to cause different returned results.

This returns 0 rows:

```
SELECT 
D.CODE, 
D.BVCMTDQTY,  
H.NUMBER, 
H.CUST_PO_NO 
FROM SALES_HISTORY_HEADER AS H 
JOIN SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL AS D ON D.NUMBER = H.NUMBER 
WHERE H.NUMBER > '0000974286'  
AND H.NUMBER < '0000974289'
```

---

This returns 8 rows:

```
SELECT 
D.CODE, 
D.BVCMTDQTY, 
H.NUMBER, 
H.CUST_PO_NO 
FROM SALES_HISTORY_DETAIL AS D
JOIN SALES_HISTORY_HEADER AS H ON D.NUMBER = H.NUMBER 
WHERE H.NUMBER > '0000974286'  
AND H.NUMBER < '0000974289'
```

Am I missing something? Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: I'm not a SQL expert, but I think FROM and JOIN order is important. I know it's a shitty comment, but hey, it's a comment.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Can you provide a sample of rows from both tables above? For an inner join (implicit when using `JOIN` alone), the order does not matter.

Comment: Also, what is the data type of `SALES_HISTORY_HEADER.NUMBER`?

Comment: This is querying a Pervasive database.

Comment: @wildplasser, OP isn't questioning the order of the records. Instead, OP is wondering why one query returns 8 records and the other, 0.

Comment: OP, better edit your title to something like "JOIN and FROM precedence" else you'll never hear the end of people who don't read telling you that tables have no default order :)

Comment: @jdl134679 I've updated the title to help folks avoid confusion.

Comment: @JNevill - thank you

Comment: @Michael Berkowski - SALES_HISTORY_HEADER.NUMBER is a string

Comment: Tip: Most people have no idea what `JOIN` does. Always use `LEFT JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`, or `RIGHT JOIN` so that there's no confusion.

Comment: Do `D.NUMBER` and `H.NUMBER` use the same character set and collation?

Comment: Is `Number` field that you are joining on a `String` in both tables? I wonder if the cardinality of your join is causing one of the tables to cast to the other, which then effects the `WHERE` clauses restrictions.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Pervasive.

Comment: @JNevill Oops, thanks.

Comment: @JNevill - yes Number is a String in both tables. Not sure what the casting effect is.

Comment: @ostrokach - I'll have to look into how to determine the character sets for each.

Comment: Ok, lots of trial and error and finally found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305454/query-returning-nothing I can't explain it as well as they do, but the gist of it is connected to how Sage BusinessVision indexes in the Pervasive db and how the join requires "and RECNO > 0" to make it work properly.